# JSF Interceptor doesn't fire

Tags: cdi, jsf-2.2, interceptor

Why my interceptor doesn't work?

**MyLog.java**

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface MyLog {
}
```

**MyLogger.java**

```
@Interceptor
@MyLog
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class MyLogger {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object log(InvocationContext context) throws Exception{ 
        System.out.println("begin " + context.getMethod().getName());
        Object obj = context.proceed();
        System.out.println("end " + context.getMethod().getName());
        return obj;
    }
}
```

**PerguntaController.java**

```
import interceptor.MyLog;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.EJBException;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
@Named("PerguntaController")
@SessionScoped
public class PerguntaController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private PerguntaFacade ejbFacade;

    @MyLog
    public List<> getAll() {
        return ejbFacade.getAll();
    }

    @MyLog
    public void update(Pergunta pergunta) {
        ejbFacade.update(pergunta);
    }
}
```

**PerguntaFacade.java**

```
import interceptor.MyLog;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
@Stateless
public class PerguntaFacade {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "WebApplicationPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @MyLog
    public List<Pergunta> getAll() {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Pergunta p", Pergunta.class).getResultList();
    }

    @MyLog
    public void update(Pergunta pergunta) {
      //do something
    }
}
```

When use getAll and update (from PerguntaController) in jsf page doesn't fire the interceptor neither getAll and update on PerguntaFacade. What im doing wrong?

Comment: Please add your imports.. is `PerguntaController` a CDI bean or a JSF Managed Bean?

Comment: It's a CDI Bean. I'm using glassfish.

Comment: Which version of GlassFish?

Comment: Are you using cdi 1.1? If not register your interceptor in beans.xml

Comment: Yes cdi 1.1 and beans.xml with bean-discovery-mode="annotated"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

On **beans.xml** with `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` doesn't work.
Then change to `bean-discovery-mode="all"` and works fine.